# Exception in JavaFX Application start method

Tags: javafx

I'm using Eclipse to write some JavaFX code, and when I will try run this code:

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(new Image(new File(getClass()
    .getResource("Things\\back.jpg").toExternalForm()).toURI().toString()));
```

The eclipse give me this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.OnOffDikra.<init>(OnOffDikra.java:55)
    at application.ToggleSwitch.<init>(ToggleSwitch.java:20)
    at application.Main.CreateContent(Main.java:19)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

The operation system is "Windows 10".

And this snapshot for my project files.

[image]

So can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You are not supposed to load a resource on your classpath using `File`. You can directly use the `getResource()` to load the resource.

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(
        new Image(getClass().getResource("/Things/back.jpg").toExternalForm()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you try to load your image as an external file ,but your image is in your source folder .

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html

> All URLs supported by URL can be passed to the constructor. If the
>   passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is
>   searched on the classpath in that case.

so you can load it just with line of code :

```
// load an image in background, displaying a placeholder while it's loading
// (assuming there's an ImageView node somewhere displaying this image)
// The image is located in default package of the classpath

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("/Things/back.jpg"));
```

Comment: it is worked for me ,when i need to load image just i write path witout using getResource

Comment: Did you move the generated JAR-file to a different location and executed it? Why would `new Image()` lookup in the current classloader? Would be new to me.

Comment: Indeed ... wasn't aware. Quoting the [documentation of Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html): ` If the passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is searched on the classpath in that case. `
Maybe you want to add this reference inside your answer aswell.

Comment: Okey i will  do .Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153151/discussion-between-menai-ala-eddine-and-fibrefox).